# how to connect visualsvn with tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, networking, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I Install TortoiseSVN and make the repository in d: drive named by svn_repo. then I make a copy of svn_repowc folder which I create three folder brunch, trunk and tags.

** PROBLEM **

I did`t  know where I make the URL to connect with other pc and I have also don't know that if I install visual svn server, how to connect it with tortoise svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN allows you to make a local repository on your machine that can be accessed with a file URI scheme. This is fine if you will be the only person to access your repository but is not safe (can be corrupted) if multiple users are accessing it at the same time. This is where Visualsvn comes in.

1. To use Visualsvn you would start it up and specify the location of your repository in the d drive.
2. Then you would configure VisualSVN with the protocol you want users to use when connecting to your repo. This should be svn, http or https.
3. Finally you should change any repositories that are accessing your repository through the file system and instead change them to use the newly configured server. For the copy on your local machine you would do a new checkout and the location would be something like (svn://localhost:(port)/myrepo) if you decide to use the svn protocol. Other computers would need to specifiy the IP address of your machine
4. The last things you would need to do would be to make sure your firewall will allow connections on your port and enable port forwarding if you want to access your svn server from outside of your LAN.

I kept it high level to give you the basic steps. You should be able to google tons of info on all of these steps.